# CORS AJAX request from a NodeJS server to a PHP server

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, node.js, cors

So I'm making an AJAX request from a node server to a PHP server. The PHP server looks like this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

echo json_encode($data);
```

The request is being sent via AngularJS list this:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {

var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://testsite.com/api/login',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: { 
        Data : { 
            email: 'test',
        }
    }
}

$http(req)
    .success(function(response){ console.log(response); })
    .error(function(){ console.log("error")});
});
```

This works perfectly. The problem starts when I run this within an NodeJS app, everything is exactly the same except that the NodeJS with ExpressJS is running `node bin/www`. The error I get is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Failed to load resource: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://testsite.com/api/login. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

Any idea on what I could be missing?

Comment: For CORS to work, the browser must make 2 requests to the PHP server. When you look at the network tab in Chrome, do you see the angular app make 2 requests?

Comment: @blablabla It seems to be making just one request actually, is there anything else I need to set up?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: The angular app first need to do the preflight request. When the server responds the domain is allowed, the actual request can take place.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this header in PHP server response

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

The client needs to know which methods the server can handle as part of the pre-flight request